# Android Lost Project Source

Tags: apk

I have a question.Recently,I have developed a new android application and in order to test I put it on my phone and having controlled on the phone,I was just going to export it to put google play but then when I click Android Tools->Export Signed Apk and my program was crashed and I got many errors.Even if  I tryied to turned them into just a warning and uncheck run error checking I could not run my program and it totally crashed.However ,before I tried to export it,I had already put apk file into phone so that I want to find out whether it is working.Now, my question is I have a working apk file called Shake.apk file in my phone but my eclipse source is totaly crashed ,can I still have a chance of loading my game into Google Play with this working apk?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you to do that, even if Google accepts it. I would rather fix my source code, then rebuild my project and then send this apk to the store. I would also recommend you to put this code in a Git repository first (such as Bitbucket or Github).I'm not saying you can't upload that apk you have, but I don't think it's "right" to upload software that you don't have its source code anymore.